# Reveal / Hide Information Panel Using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display an overlay panel with some additional information on top of an image when a button is clicked.  The HTML looks like below and there can be an unlimited amount of these sections.

```
<div class="half">

    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/BiyaRiver.JPG" alt="">                            

    <div class="information"">

        <p>Left Image Overlay Information</p>

    </div> <!-- .information -->

    <div class="info-icon"></div><!-- .info-icon -->            

</div> <!-- .half -->
```

The '.information' overlay is set to display: none in the CSS and initially I had some JQuery code as below:

```
$(".info-icon").click(function () {

    if( $(".information").is(":hidden") ) {

        $(this).css("background","url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/close-128.png");

        $(".information").css("display","block");   

    } else {

        $(this).css("background","url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/app-types-in-grey/128/info_512pxGREY.png");

        $(".information").css("display","none");

    }

});
```

However this affected all of the panels at once and was not what I was after.

So I've got to the code below which is closer to what I want but it's not working as expected.  You can reveal the panel for each section but not close it until you get to the very last section and then it shows and reveals as expected.

```
$(".info-icon").click(function () {

    if( $(".information").is(":hidden") ) {

        $(this).css("background","url(http://butterscotch.wecreatedev.co.uk/wp-content/themes/butterscotch-child/img/close.svg");
        $(this).closest('.half').find('.information').css("display","block");

    } else {

        $(this).css("background","url(http://butterscotch.wecreatedev.co.uk/wp-content/themes/butterscotch-child/img/information.svg");
        $(this).closest('.half').find('.information').css("display","none");    

    }

});
```

JS Fiddle has been created to demo the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/g83Lbodu/4/

All time and help is greatly appreciated with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to update your `if` condition to satisfy the closest `.information` div.  Also, you don't need to set the CSS directly, you should be able to use `.hide()` and `.show()`

So your new code should read as follows:

```
$(".info-icon").click(function () {

    if( $(this).closest('.half').find('.information').is(":hidden") ) {

        $(this).css("background","url(http://butterscotch.wecreatedev.co.uk/wp-content/themes/butterscotch-child/img/close.svg");
        $(this).closest('.half').find('.information').show();

    } else {

        $(this).css("background","url(http://butterscotch.wecreatedev.co.uk/wp-content/themes/butterscotch-child/img/information.svg");
        $(this).closest('.half').find('.information').hide();    

    }

});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g83Lbodu/7/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend simplifying this quite a bit and letting CSS handle the style changes:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g83Lbodu/11/)

JQuery

```
$(".info-icon").click(function() {
  $('.half').has(this).toggleClass('overlay-visible');
});
```

CSS

```
.overlay-visible .information { 
  display: block;
}
.overlay-visible .info-icon {
  background: url('http://butterscotch.wecreatedev.co.uk/wp-content/themes/butterscotch-child/img/close.svg') 100% 100%;
}
```